# iOS - UITextField - No cursor when editing text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added a UITextField so I can type some text in my app. I can type text, and the text is displayed. However, there is no cursor, and so there's no way to tell what you are modifying before modifying it.

Is it an expected behavior ? Is there any way to show the cursor ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be your cursor color match yout textfield color that's why it's not displayed

Comment: check tint colour of that UITextField.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your cursor color is similar to text background color

you can change by this

OBj-C   `[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Swift   `UITextField.appearance().tintColor = .black`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed it. However I see that each time I change the cursor position, it goes to the end of the word, not exactly where I clicked. Is this normal ? I know this is another question, but if you have a solution..

Comment: Okay, I'm new to iOS. I just needed to long click, and then there is a buble where you can move inside a word.

Comment: how you change  cursor position by the finger or using  any code by finger it should move with your finger position  as buble appear

Comment: I use the tintColor this way in Swift 4 + Xcode 9.2 ==> myTextField.tintColor = .white works fine. I use Mr.Darwish code as sample.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is not default behavior of UITextField that your are not see cursor BTW

In the `viewDidAppear` method just write

```
yourTxtFieldObject.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: yourTextField.tintColor = .white hides it